# Gradle fails at creating fat jar on antlr sourceset after clean, succeeds otherwise

Tags: gradle, deployment, jar, antlr, fatjar

I'm experiencing a weird behaviour on my mutliproject Gradle build. The project having issues is open source, so those who want to dig more into the build are welcome to take a look [here](https://github.com/AlchemistSimulator/Alchemist/tree/develop), on the branch develop.

In the parent project, I defined a `fatJar` task as follows:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: subprojects.compileJava) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Alchemist',
        'Implementation-Version': rootProject.version,
        'Main-Class': 'it.unibo.alchemist.Alchemist'
    }
    baseName = "${rootProject.name}-redist"
    from(configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }) {
        // remove all signature files
        exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
        exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
        exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
        exclude 'build'
        exclude '.gradle'
        exclude 'build.gradle'
        exclude 'gradle'
        exclude 'gradlew'
        exclude 'gradlew.bat'
    }
    with jar
}
```

The one subproject where the failure is generated is a bit peculiar, as it uses ANTLR (I'm omitting dependencies and other code that I deem unnecessary to understand the problem at hand).

```
apply plugin: 'antlr'
sourceSets {
    antlr
}
generateGrammarSource {
    arguments += ["-visitor", "-package", "it.unibo.alchemist.biochemistrydsl"]
    def target = new File('src/antlr/java/')
    if ((target.exists() && target.isDirectory()) || target.mkdirs()) {
        outputDirectory = target
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("$target is not an existing directory and could not be created as such.")
    }
}
compileAntlrJava.dependsOn('generateGrammarSource')
compileJava.dependsOn('compileAntlrJava')
```

Now, when running `./gradlew clean && ./gradlew fatJar` from within the parent project, I get a failure, with the following exception (some parts omitted for brevity):

```
> Failed to create MD5 hash for file '[my project folder]/alchemist/alchemist-incarnation-biochemistry/build/classes/java/antlr' as it does not exist.
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':fatJar' property 'rootSpec$1$1' during up-to-date check.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.snapshotTaskFiles(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:331)
<snip>
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to create MD5 hash for file '[my project folder]/alchemist/alchemist-incarnation-biochemistry/build/classes/java/antlr' as it does not exist.
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.DefaultFileHasher.hash(DefaultFileHasher.java:45)
<snip>
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: [my project folder]/alchemist/alchemist-incarnation-biochemistry/build/classes/java/antlr (Is a directory)
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.DefaultFileHasher.hash(DefaultFileHasher.java:38)
```

The file that the system is complaining being a folder is actually there and is actually a folder, but it is supposed to be indeed.
Now, what puzzles me is that if `./gradlew fatJar` is called a second time, it successfully completes.
This is reproducible on diverse systems, varying the Gradle version (remaining on versions 4.x) and operating systems (Arch Linux and MacOS X).

Comment: Same problem here!